# Vue: Detect when dynamic component is switched

Tags: html, vue.js, html5-canvas, vue-cli

I have a tabbed interface in Vue where one of those tabs has a canvas element that is updated every frame. The tab windows are implemented using `<component :is="curComponent" />`

I don't want this canvas element being updated every frame if the user isn't on the tab that requires it, so I was wondering if there was any way to detect when the `<component />` element switches? It doesn't seem to trigger the `destroyed()` method at all.

Edit: here is the code. Even when the tab is switched "destroyed," is never printed to the console window, leading me to believe that the component is never destroyed

```
//in EditorWindow
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="currentEditor" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
import LevelEditor from './editor_level/LevelMain';
import ArtEditor from './editor_art/ArtMain';
import LogicEditor from './editor_logic/LogicMain';

export default {
    name: 'EditorWindow',
    components: {
        LevelEditor
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['selectedTab']),
        currentEditor(){
            switch(this.selectedTab){
                case 'level':
                    return LevelEditor;
                case 'art':
                    return ArtEditor;
                case 'logic':
                    return LogicEditor;
                default:
                    return LevelEditor;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

//in ArtEditor Component
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
import artCanvas from './artCanvasScript';

export default {
    name: "ArtCanvas",
    data() {
        return {
            canvasEl: null
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.resize();
        this.setup();
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['selectedTab'])
    },
    methods:{
        resize(event = null){
            let wrapper = this.$refs.artCanvas;
            let canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
            canvas.width = wrapper.clientWidth;
            canvas.height = wrapper.clientHeight;
        },
        setup(){
            this.canvasEl = new artCanvas(this.$refs.canvas);
            this.canvasEl.setup();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{this.update()});
        },
        update(){
            this.resize();
            if (this.selectedTab == "art"){
                this.canvasEl.update();
                window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{this.update()});
            }
        },
        beforeDestroy(){
            console.log("beforeDestroy")
        },
        destroyed(){
            this.canvasEl = null;
        }
    }
}
```

also I am absolutely hammered atm, so I med edit this tomorrow when I sover up to make it more clear

Comment: Have you verified that the canvas is still being updated? Unless you're using [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components), the tab content does not stay around

Comment: As you can see in [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bash-9b87v?file=/index.html), when not using `<keep-alive>`, the `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` hooks are definitely called

Comment: The component stores an imported class in the data() that gets updated every frame, and prints "updated," to the console. "updated," is still printed every frame, so that at least tells me what's stored in the "data" is still kept around

Comment: Using `setInterval` / `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`? Whatever sets up the update loop would have to be torn down in `beforeDestroy` or `destroyed`. Please show some code if you want help

Comment: Why do you have `components: { LevelEditor }`?

Comment: `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` are life-cycle hooks. Move them out of `methods`

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU!